# Can a website be HTTP and HTTPS at the same time?

Tags: http, url, https, redirect

Somehow I've stumbled on this website that has an http url and an https url at the same time:

http://www.actbrain-vn.com/

https://www.actbrain-vn.com/

I'm not that seasoned in web development yet, so here are my questions:

How does that work? Why doesn't the http url redirect to the newer https? Could this be oversight? If I'm to turn an http website into an https website, what should I do so that this won't happen?

Comment: you just need a permanent redirect from http to https in your server conf file. It will be great if you can let us know about your web server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http` runs on port 80, and `https` runs on TCP port 443. They can both be open at the same time, they can even serve different websites. In some ways they are 2 different websites.

To avoid this you can simply close down port 80, or alternatively, make sure that website served on port 80 always sends a redirect to the https website.

Answer (score 1):

The part before the "://" is the communication **protocol** ; here HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) and HTTPS (HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure), which is HTTP over TLS (or formerly SSL).

A protocol is a set of rules for a given communication type.

Your examples shows accessing the same ressource through different protocols.

It is like going to Rome: you can use the highway or a regional road: both lead to the same destination.

There are several other protocols, like FTP or SMB for instance.

So, unless HTTP was redirected to HTTPS (which is often the case), there is no reason why you could not reach the site in both HTTP and HTTPS if both protocols are accepted by the server.